# Executing ping test communication between three instance EC2

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, ping, subnet

I created three instances in AWS, at same VPC group and subnet, to do a student's project with docker and kubernetes.

But, when I try to realize the connection test with PING, any instances don't ping and it lost 100% packet. But, when I try to ping a host out of my network it's work.

My Security group is configured to allow connections:

- SSH 22
- TCP 8080 / 443
- ICMP

Help me, please.

Comment: Please show the actual Security Group configuration (eg a screenshot) -- there are more fields that are important to see. Are all instances associated with the same Security Group? Are you pinging the Public or Private IP address of the instances?

Comment: John, Thank's for help-me.

Comment: Please show the _FULL_ details of the security group configuration, including the Source/Destination field. Perhaps a screenshot? Are all instances associated with the same Security Group?